# Emgu CvInvoke.CalcHist throws exception OpenCV: 0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I want to create a histogram from a grayscale image using `CvInvoke.CalcHist()`.
For some reason the code is throwing an exception of  `0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowRange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows`.

I saw the solution on [Emgu - CalcHist _rowRange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747411/emgu-calchist-rowrange-error) but it didn't work for me. Also I don't see why `VectorOfMat` should work when UMat doesn't. They are both implementers of `InputArrayOfArrays`...

This is my code. Any help will be appreciated:

```cs
            #region Load image
            Image<Bgr, Byte> img = null;
            try
            {
                img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imagePath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Image for file {0} was not loaded", imagePath));
            }
            #endregion

            #region Convert the image to grayscale
            UMat gray = new UMat();
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(img, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
            #endregion

            #region Calculate histogram

            Mat hist = new Mat();
            
            try
            {
                UMat v = new UMat();
                
                CvInvoke.CalcHist(gray, new int[] { 0 }, null, hist, new int[] { 256 }, new float[] { 0, 256 }, false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

So the solution was indeed to use the VectorOfUmat.
This way, the input to CalcHist is a single cell variable. The variable is the grayscale image. See the code below for the correction:

```
        VectorOfUMat vou = new VectorOfUMat();
        vou.Push(gray);
        Mat hist = new Mat();
        
        try
        {
            UMat v = new UMat();
            CvInvoke.CalcHist(vou, new int[] { 0 }, null, hist, new int[] { 256 }, new float[] { 0, 256 }, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
```